# xampp script from php file doesn't carry over to html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file that involves a button that toggles visibility

```
echo "<button onclick = \"toggle('showDetails')\">expand</button>" ;

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "   function toggle(id) { \n";
echo "       var e = document.getElementById(id)\n";
echo "       if(e.style.display == 'block')\n";
echo "          e.style.display = 'none';\n";
echo "       else\n";
echo "          e.style.display = 'block';\n";
echo "    }";
echo " </script>";
```

and it works perfectly fine on my php page. But when I go to the html page that calls my php page, the script doesn't work. I tried putting my script in the header of the html page, and the body of the html page, but to no avail. What do I need to do to get my button to work on the html page.

EDIT:
Here is the showDetails element:

```
echo "<div id =\"showDetails\" style=\"display:none\">" ;
echo "<strong>client_address:</strong>" ;
echo $client_address;
echo "<br>" ;
echo "<strong>client_date:</strong>" ;
echo $client_date;
echo "</div>" ;
```

I also opened up my html page and used the google chrome inspector. When I click on the button on the html page, I get the error in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined

Comment: Please add the code to your question where you echo  the **showDetails** element that needs to be toggled.

Comment: I have updated my question with the showDetails element as well as the console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this `php` file via an `ajax`-style method (using `XMLHttpRequest`) and inject the response in your existing page with an assignment to `innerHTML`, the `javacscript` embedded in `script` tags will not execute. In your case this means the `toggle` function will never be defined.

There are several ways to solve this:

- Define the `toggle` function in the `HTML` page that is making this `http` request. That way the `script` tag with this function will be there from the start, and executed at page load. It does not matter that the `toggle` function is just sitting there and doing nothing, up until the moment you call the `menu.php` file which will send back the button.
- Use `jQuery` or similar library which has functions that perform such `http` requests **and** execute whatever is in embedded `script`tags.

With the second option, you could write:

```
$("#menuDiv").load("menu.php");
```

There are several other ways to achieve this, and I refer to the [many previous answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20execute%20script%20ajax%20site:stackoverflow.com) to this question.

Note also that there is a semi-colon before the `else` in the `javascript` which breaks your `if`-`else` construct:

```
echo "          e.style.display = 'none';\n";
```

Do instead:

```
echo "          e.style.display = 'none'\n";
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: When I put all the code you provided in [pdf fiddle light](http://phpfiddle.org/lite), with the fix on the semi--colon, the button works as expected. But what do you mean with "the html page that calls my php page"? Maybe I missed something there, because the `html` is produced by `php`. Maybe you are referring to another `html` page?

Comment: I have an html page file. And it calls upon a php page as such var menu=new XMLHttpRequest(); menu.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (menu.readyState==4 && menu.status==200){
       document.getElementById("menuDiv").innerHTML=menu.responseText;
     }
   }
   menu.open("GET","menu.php",true);
   menu.send();

Comment: Well, that should be information you should have put in your question from the start, because this explains the behaviour you have. Could you add this code to your question? In the mean time I have updated my answer.